# How to redirect to an action in different controller in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm in an action of CustomersController and I want to redirect to another action of a different controller.

I tried to use

```
RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

but it doesn't work!
How can I do it ?

Additionally, how can I pass some parameters?

Comment: please do search on google, before asking it here.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are returning the result of `RedirectToAction`

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = 5 });
```